# I broke my Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel, rootkit

For a college Security project, I had to write a rootkit module from my Ubuntu 14.04. The rootkit was not supposed to harm the kernel, just hide processes and ports. However after running the module on my machine, my Ubuntu got reset to this helpless state. I can't change proxy, change desktop background, lock application on the side bar, use git commands anymore... etc. I don't know why this happened but I was hoping upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 would fix the problem, but it didn't. I have Windows 7 concurrently and it still works fine. Because I don't understand the problem, I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Can you not do a reinstall, or did you not keep a separate home partition?

Comment: I do have a separate home partition but I was hoping there would be an easier solution.

Comment: User3113723 has a good solution. Does that not work for you?

Comment: @User3113723 I think so but I'm not very familiar with installing/uninstalling OS so I need to learn how to do it first so I don't mess things up any further.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be self inflicted and part of home work

Comment: Next time you run a kernel thing, try in a virtual box?

Answer (score 4):

1. backup your data. possibly boot with livecd/liveusb, mount hd, and backup that way.
2. wipe hard drive, install fresh ubuntu.
3. do rootkit dev work in virtual machines from now on.

seriously, there's no way anyone here can figure out how to fix the results of the rootkit you wrote for class.

Comment: +1, we can't fix it when someone is messing with things they don't understand!